# Spring mvc with thymeleaf

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

How to use thymeleaf to add an object of String without any pojos?

```
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public String s(Model model){
    model.add("e","model test");
    return "view1";
}
```

what to do next to get the data from the view ?!

Answer (score 1):

These are very well explained in [Thymeleaf docs](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html), have you gone through them?

```
<p th:text="${e}">1</p>
```

Comment: thank you but i know who to display it .... i just wanna to see who to retrive the value to the controller class as like 
@RequestMapping("/get")
public String s(@ModelAttribute String , Model model)